# Phoenix.Token for API logout?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I know that you can use Phoenix.Token for generating and verifying tokens for the API.

I generate it this way:

```
session = %{token: Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user", user.id)}
```

And verifying:

```
Phoenix.Token.verify(conn, "user", token)
```

I do not understand how I can organize the process of "deleting" a session when the user logout. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with session? Maybe you should look at `Plug.Conn.delete_session`?

Comment: @webdeb No, I wrote incorrectly, this is not a session. I meant how to make the token become invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Token is a **signed** string, `Phoenix.Token.verify` will just check if the Token was generated with the real **secret**. There is no way to make the token invalid.

Depending on what you need, you could store the token inside a user related table, like `auth_tokens` and when the user logs out, you can delete the the token from there. And create a new one, when the user logs in again.

The main purpose of the Token is to make sure, that it was generated on a trusted instance, once created, the `verify` function will always accept such a token.